# Create table and insert a row if the table does not exist

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm looking for a way to check whether a table exists with SQLite and C#. If the table does not exist, I would like to create and populate with an initial row of data. If it does exist the program is to do nothing.

```sql
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';
```

The above always returns -1, regardless of whether the table exists or not.

Comment: SQlite supports `CREATE TABLE ... IF NOT EXISTS`, https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html 
Afterwards you could do a `SELECT COUNT` statement to check if the table is empty.

Comment: Yes I was originally using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS and then inserting the values afterwards. Trouble is I can't seem to find a way to only insert the values IF the table doesn't exist and has just been created.